# Un-stack a bart chart in Tableau

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api

I have created one view in tableau with 3 variables FTE1 , FTE2 and FTE 3. I wanted FTE1 and FTE2 as barchart and FTE3 as line.

I have created this using this [Tableau article](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-graph-that-combines-a-bar-chart-with-two-or-more-lines).

Problem is that now FTE1 and FTE2 bars are stacked and I would like to have on bar next to the other one instead (See attached pic).

How can I un-stack them?

Thanks![image]

Comment: can we consider this question as answered? if so, please accept the answer in order to "close" the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're quite proficient with some Tableau tricks, I would suggest reading this article covering various techniques to achieve what you need:

https://vizartpandey.com/combined-bar-and-line-chart/

Comment: I saw this before yeah. It looks quite complex tbh. I will have a try if I get some time. Thanks!!

Comment: Indeed; but I would say it provides different ways to achieve your need based on your scenario... if you feel that the link can be enough to solve your problem, please accept the answer in order to marke the question as answered.